# Will gc collect the objects while the array set to nil in Golang?

Tags: go, memory-management, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have an array that holds many objects. When I set the array to nil, will gc collect all the objects holded by the array?

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "runtime"
)

type B struct {
    bb []int
}

func NewB() *B {
    return new(B)
}

func main()  {
    var bs = make([]*B, 10)
    for i:=0; i<10; i++ {
        bs[i] = NewB()
        bs[i].bb = make([]int, 1000000)
    }

    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    println("begin gc")
    //for i:=0; i<10; i++ {
    //  bs[i] = nil
    //}
    bs = nil
    runtime.GC()
    time.Sleep(time.Second*2)
    runtime.GC()
    time.Sleep(time.Second*2)
}
```

First, I set `bs = nil`, all the two gc infos show `76->76->76 MB`, this means gc does not free the memory.
Then, I add the for loop code in the slash statement, the first gc info shows `76->76->0 MB`, the second gc info shows `0->0->0 MB`.
So I'm confused that, when I set `bs = nil`, there is no pointer referenced to all the objects, why gc does not free the objects? should all the objects explicitly set to nil?

Comment: In Go there is no need to worry about GC. If something is unreachable it _will_ be collected. These types of test for GC just reveal that there might not be any heap alloc at all. There is nothing to learn here. GC works, you can rely on it.

Comment: Also, that's a **slice**, not an array.

Answer (score 7):

If you compile with escape analysis turned on you'll see that bs doesn't escape and so is allocated on the stack, not the heap

```
go run -gcflags '-m -l' gc.go
# command-line-arguments
./gc.go:13:12: new(B) escapes to heap
./gc.go:20:18: make([]int, 1000000) escapes to heap
./gc.go:17:15: main make([]*B, 10) does not escape
```

so although you've nil'd `bs` the slice that bs was pointing to is still considered live by the gc by virtue of being on the stack. If you push your code down into its own func, and then GC after it returns, you'll see that the GC does reclaim all the memory.

```
func main() {
    alloc()
    runtime.GC()
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
}

func alloc() {
    var bs = make([]*B, 10)
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        bs[i] = NewB()
        bs[i].bb = make([]int, 1000000)
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    println("begin gc")
    bs = nil
    runtime.GC()
}



begin gc
gc 5 @1.003s 0%: 0.003+0.052+0.021 ms clock, 0.026+0/0.036/0.055+0.17 ms cpu, 76->76->76 MB, 137 MB goal, 8 P (forced)
gc 6 @1.003s 0%: 0.001+0.037+0.018 ms clock, 0.010+0/0.036/0.023+0.15 ms cpu, 76->76->0 MB, 152 MB goal, 8 P (forced)
```

Comment: A good thing to learn from this answer is how to write code which will minimize your allocations, esp if you are allocating too much memory this should be carefully dealt with. Thanks @superfell for the insight.

Comment: "considered live by the gc by virtue of being on the stack" - GC only operates on the heap. The GC doesn't consider anything on the stack at all - live, dead, or otherwise.

Comment: The stack is considered a root by the gc, see the comments in https://golang.org/src/runtime/mgc.go, which is why the heap allocated things pointed to from the stack aren't gc'd inside the alloc().